# Regular expression to match numbers up to two decimal place

Tags: javascript, regex

What can I use for a JavasScript regular expression to match numbers up to two decimal places?

Valid Examples:

> 123.22
>
> 3
>
> 22
>
> 654
>
> 9292929292.12
>
> 0.21
>
> 3.1

Invalid Examples:

> 221.1232
>
> 4.23332
>
> 12.763

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before adding them to a question. If you read the tag excerpt for [tag:nsregularexpression], you'll find it is about iOS development. There is a [tag:regex] tag for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If leading zeros are invalid as in 01.23 and 000.2 then

```
^((?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

```js
var re = /^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;

console.log(
  re.test('123.22'),
  re.test('221.1232')
)
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/kB7rM3/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]